# Chronometer set wrong long value

Tags: android, android-widget

Set manually long value to chronometer.my long value is correct but when I set this to `chronometer.setBase()`it display specially character instead of correct time.

```
    // hourInt = 4
    // minInt = 34
    // secInt = 40
    Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                    cal1.set(Calendar.HOUR, hourInt);
                    cal1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minInt);
                    cal1.set(Calendar.SECOND, secInt);

                long codeBase = cal1.getTime().getTime();
                System.out.println("Code Base..."+codeBase);
 chronometer.setBase(codeBase);
                chronometer.start();
```

it display special chraracter like 00:0) and 00:0* and all special character.
how to set custom long value.

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with this myself until I managed to figure it out through trial and error.

`Chronometer.setBase()` wants millis based on the `elapsed real time`. This means that epoch milliseconds don't work. In order to be able to use epoch milliseconds, you have to call `Chronometer.setBase()` like this:

```
chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() -
    System.currentTimeMillis() + codeBase);
```

The math effectively converts the epoch milliseconds to elapsed real time milliseconds.